# Check folder size oid snmp on server centos?

Tags: linux, centos, snmp, oid

I 'm  use command disk oid (.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9.1.2.1)  [reference](http://kaivanov.blogspot.com/2012/02/linux-snmp-oids-for-cpumemory-and-disk.html) 
set file "snmpd.conf" and restart serviec (service snmpd restart)

in file snmpd.conf"

disk /var/logs 10%

It is output [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4XQXKz8Z1RWSGN3clR4N2tvUnc/view)
but set file snmpd.conf

disk / 10%

It is work

but I want check size pathfile "/var/logs"
What should I do ?

Comment: Not a programming question. Questions about server administration should go on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess:
is `/var/logs` mounted from a partition? You can't check the space used by a generic directory, it must be a mount point.